Move buttons to East with grid method
So a little stylistic thing I want to do is move some buttons to the east side of the window while having them all on the same row.
Sounds easy enough and the grid method has a sticky parameter that should make this easy to do, right? No.
This is the basic code
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("200x200")

btn1 = Button(window, text="btn1")
btn1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="E")
btn2 = Button(window, text="btn2")
btn2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="E")

window.mainloop()

What I want is:
-------------------------
|         ------ ------ |
|         |btn1| |btn2| |
|         ------ ------ |
-------------------------

What I'm getting is:
-------------------------
| ------ ------         |
| |btn1| |btn2|         |
| ------ ------         |
-------------------------

Which is sticking to the West even though I specified East
What am I doing wrong? How can I get the result I want?

Give column 0 some weigth. It will force column 1 and 2 to right.
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("200x200")
window.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
btn1 = Button(window, text="btn1")
btn1.grid(row=0, column=1)
btn2 = Button(window, text="btn2")
btn2.grid(row=0, column=2)

window.mainloop()

Another way to do this is using pack() and Frame()
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry("200x200")
cbframe = Frame(window)
btn1 = Button(cbframe, text="btn1")
btn1.pack(side="right", fill=None, expand=False)
btn2 = Button(cbframe, text="btn2")
btn2.pack(side="right", fill=None, expand=False)

cbframe.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=False)
window.mainloop()

